# Server side rendering with react-router

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I'm trying to get react-router to run on the server with the simplest Hello World example, and whatever I do, the props in the callback is always undefined. Trying since two days, it seems the API has changed quite drastically and all answers I found where related to the old API.

So here the super simple code example:

```
import http from 'http'
import React from 'react'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { match, RoutingContext } from 'react-router'
import fs from 'fs'


class Home extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <div>{this.props.children}</div>         
    }
}

class Hello extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <h1>Hello World</h1>
    }
}

class Routes extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <Route path="/" component={Home}>
                <Route path="hello" component={Hello} />
            </Route>
        )
    }
}

http.createServer((req, res) => {

    match({ Routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirect, props) => {
        if (props){
            let markup = renderToString(<RouterContext {...props}/>)
            res.write(markup)
            res.end()
        } else {
            res.write("not found")
            res.end()
        }

    })  
}).listen(8888);
```

If I type in /hello in the browser, why does it say "not found"? According to the documentation and API it should work like that.. what am I missing?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Routes should not be a function or class, just an object of JSX `<Route>s`. The property that `match()` is looking for is `routes`, not `Routes`. Those two fixes should get you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

Interrobang gave me the right hints and i managed to make it work, here the working example if somebody is interested:

```
import http from 'http'
import React from 'react'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { Route, match, RouterContext } from 'react-router'
import fs from 'fs'


class Home extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <div>{this.props.children}</div>         
    }
}

class Hello extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <h1>Hello World</h1>
    }
}

const routes = (
    <Route path="/" component={Home}>
        <Route path="hello" component={Hello} />
    </Route>    
)

http.createServer((req, res) => {

    match({ routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirect, props) => {
        if (props){
            let markup = renderToString(<RouterContext {...props}/>)
            res.write(markup)
            res.end()
        } else {
            res.write("not found")
            res.end()
        }

    })  
}).listen(8888);
```